# Extreme points of $f(x)= 2x+\cot x$

Tags: calculus, functions, extreme-value-analysis

I want to find the extreme points of the function $f(x) =2x+\cot x$.
I began by observing that the function is defined on $D=\mathbb{R} - \{k\pi | k\in \mathbb{Z} \} $. Now, $f'(x) =2-\frac{1}{\sin^2 x} $ $\forall x \in D$. I tried to study $f'$'s sign, but I don' t know how to get around the points where the function is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$D_f = \mathbb{R} - \{k\pi, k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$

$f(x) = 2x+\cot x $

$f'(x) = 2 - \csc^2x$

> At extreme points, $f'(x) = 0$

$2 = \csc^2x \implies \sin^2x = \frac{1}{2} = \sin^2\frac{\pi}{4}$

> $$x = 2k\pi\pm\pi/4$$

These are the extreme points.

It'd be clear from the graph below of $f(x)$
[image]

Comment: Well there are two problems with this. Not every $a$ for which $f'(a) =0$ is an extreme point and you also left out the points where the function isn't differentiable.

Comment: Well, the function is not differentiable at $k\pi$ and the domain doesn't contain those points.

Comment: Right, but this still doesn't prove that all these points really are extreme points.

Comment: find $f''(x) = 2\csc^2 x \cot x$. For e.g., at $\pi/4$, $f''(\pi/4) = 4\implies$ local minimum and $f''(-\pi/4) = -4\implies$ local maximum

Comment: Thank you, this completes the proof.

Comment: You're welcome !

Comment: Exactly, The Second Order Derivative Really helps in this case